# Merging wide data into a long dataframe format R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, merge

I have two dataframes, one long and one wide, and I am trying to merge the two together. I have demographic information in the wide format that I need to bring into the long format for analysis. When I merge the two dataframes, the information from the wide format only populates one row and the remainder are blank.

Here is some sample data to show what I'm working with and the outcome I'm hoping for. The only problem is that the merge works in the sample data but not in my actual data.

```r
df_long <- data.frame (id  = c(123, 123, 123, 345, 345),
                       x = c("abc", "cgf", "add", "wer", "nko"),
                       y = c(234, 234, 5436, 73435, 2353))
```

```r
df_wide <- data.frame(id = c(123, 345),
                      person = c("Mom", "Teen"))
```

When I use this code to merge the sample data, it results in how I want the data

```r
df_goal <- merge(df_long, df_wide)
```

And when I use this code, it has the right number of variables, but 0 observations.

```r
real_merged <- merge(real_long, real_wide)
```

To fix it, I add the `all = T` argument but I get more observations than I would expect. It looks like the merge just adds the number of observations from df_wide to df_long, but doesn't match them by the ID. I have visually confirmed that there are matching IDs, so this shouldn't happen.

My real data has over 100k rows and 150 variables. I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it so I'm just throwing it out there.

I've tried using different arguments in the merge function like `all = T` and also not using it, as well as the `by =`  and `by.x =` but none results in what I am looking for. I've also looked into using `melt()`, but I can't get it to work.

Since there are no errors and it doesn't reproduce in the sample data it makes it almost impossible to troubleshoot. I'm hoping that someone out there has had a similar issue and knows the fix.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Brian_p! I suggested an edit to your question that cleans up some of the formatting; namely, code blocks (more than one line) should have "code fences" each on their own line, starting with `\`\`\`r` (and no code) and then `\`\`\``, again, each completely isolated on the line of text. Two good references for formatting code are https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189 and https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. (This is mostly aesthetic, but occasionally mis-formatted code is a little harder to read, so it's something I often try to help clean up.)

Comment: @r2evans, thanks for the info on formatting posts. I'll look into the links you provided and try to update the code in my example.

Comment: The `id` values may be slightly different, even though they look the same when displayed, causing the rows to not match in the join. If the `id`s should be integers, try changing them in both using `as.integer` before merging. This will fix the problem if e.g. the `123` is actually `123.000000001` being displayed as `123`.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan, I double checked and the ```typeof()``` and ```class()``` for both variables are the same.

Comment: What are they though? If they are doubles they could look the same be have different values.

Comment: They are character values. I should have reflected that more accurately in the sample data I provided.

Comment: Okay, I was able to figure it out. I was importing SPSS files into R and one of the dataframes had the variable labels attached which seems to be why the ID values weren't linking? I'm not sure why that was happening, but I saved the SPSS file as an Excel file and then imported that into R and the merge worked perfectly. Thank you all for taking the time to review this and for providing your input, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to specify that you want to keep all data of one of your tables, not all data of both (`all=TRUE` keeps all data of both tables, which is the default).

```
df_long <- data.frame (id  = c(123, 123, 123, 345, 345),
                       x = c("abc", "cgf", "add", "wer", "nko"),
                       y = c(234, 234, 5436, 73435, 2353))

df_wide <- data.frame(id = c(123, 345),
                      person = c("Mom", "Teen"))

df_goal <- merge(df_long, df_wide, all.x=TRUE, by="id")
```

The output looks as like this:

[image]

Here `all.x=TRUE` means that extra rows will be added to the output, one for each row in x that has no matching row in y. These rows will have NAs in those columns that are usually filled with values from y. Inversely, if they do have a match than the value of y will be used.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried using ```all.x = TRUE``` but then none of the values in df_wide are added, they are all NAs. But I need the data in df_wide to populate in every row of df_long.

Comment: Are you sure you have no typo in your code? If I run the above line with your example the results is as expected. I have updated the code with a fully functional example.

Comment: no, I don't have any typos. As I mentioned in my post, it works in the sample data, but not in my actual data. It's really weird and I can't explain it. I've tried to merge the two dataframes in multiple ways and playing with different versions of the ```merge()``` arguments, but I cant get it to work. I've restarted my R Session thinking maybe that was it, but that didn't resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was able to figure it out.

I was importing SPSS files into R using the `foreign()` package and one of the dataframes had the variable labels attached which seems to be why the ID values weren't linking.
[Here is what the variable labels looked like after reading the data into R.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzWdQ.png) There is a sort of sub-label for the variable name. I'm not sure why that was happening, but I saved the SPSS file as an Excel file and then read that into R. I then retried the merge with the new dataframe and it worked perfectly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).